# mvc entity framework many-to-many relationship of entities from multiple database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

so I have 2 entities from 2 database. 'tblApp' is from Db1 and 'tblGroup' is from Db2 
.How can I build many to many relationship of 2 tables from 2 databases

Currently I have

```
 public class EFDbContextDb1 : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Group> tblGroup { get; set; }
            // the problem is 'tblApp' is in the Db2 database
            // so I guess I should do something here
        public DbSet<App> tblApp{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().ToTable("tblGroup");

            modelBuilder.Entity<App>()
               .HasMany(g => g.tblGroup)
               .WithMany(a => a.tblApp)
               .Map(m =>
               {
                   m.MapLeftKey("AppID");
                   m.MapRightKey("GroupID");
                   m.ToTable("AppGroup");
               });
        }

    }

public class EFDbContextDb2 : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<App> tblsApp{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<App>().ToTable("tblApp");

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

the connection string to connect with 'Db1' and 'Db2'

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContextDb1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=Db1;Initial Catalog=Security;Integrated Security=true;" />
    <add name="EFDbContextDb2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=Db2;Initial Catalog=ServerStatus;Integrated Security=true;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you can't.  EF can only deal with one context (and even schema) at a time.

However,  you can:

- Create a service layer (with its own set of entities) and place the joining logic there. And now the service entities become a collage of information pulled from multiple locations.
- Create table-valued functions that call pull information from both locations and return the joined information in s format that one EF context would encompass in a single object.
- Use something like Dapper.net and use synonyms in the database and query it to your own model.

Comment: Thank you! can you also elaborate on the service layer?

Comment: Create,  for example, `MyService` that,  internally, has references to the two contexts, makes the calls, then assembles an "`AppAndGroups`" object it hands off.

Comment: You are right you cant have a cross DB association but you can have multiple schemas in the same DBContext and query between them (im not too sure if this extends to nav properties but im pretty sure it does) You do this via the .ToTable("schema","Table") mapping

Comment: FYI, you can use synonyms with EF Code First as well.  They work just fine.  Using them in DB or Model first is a lot more difficult.

Comment: @mysteryman agreed.  But sometimes you can burn more hours trying to implement them, thinking it's going to be a breeze,  only to find out that doinga little more architecture pays off sooner.

Comment: I never had a problem with them, although I tend to do "Database First" and reverse engineer to DbContext with the EF Power Tools for both DB's, then manually merge the two DbContexts.  Which takes a little time up front, but doesn't take a lot to maintain afterwards.

Comment: I tend to stick with code first and migrations which flash make that a but more complicated.  Though I tend to like having services adjusts to keep business logic in one place with multiple access points.